# Trying to use Infinispan as a JPA/Hibernate second level cache provider, without success

Tags: hibernate, jboss5.x, second-level-cache, infinispan

I would like to use Infinispan to cache repeatedly called queries.

I followed this tutorial to set up Hibernate for this:

[Using Infinispan as JPA-Hibernate Second Level Cache Provider](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Using+Infinispan+as+JPA-Hibernate+Second+Level+Cache+Provider).

I followed every step, and while the log shows that Infinispan is used as a second-level cache and query caching enabled, no queries seem to be cached.

I also tried out this tutorial:
[Infinispan as Hibernate 2nd-Level Cache in JBoss AS 5.x](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Infinispan+as+Hibernate+2nd-Level+Cache+in+JBoss+AS+5.x), also without success.

Here are excerpts of the configuration I've done:

(orm.xml)

```
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <named-query name="retrievePolicySet">
        <query>from PSTRepresentationType p where p.realm=? AND p.policySetType.policySetId=?</query>
        <hint name="org.hibernate.cacheable" value="true" />
    </named-query>

    <named-query name="retrievePolicySetList">
        <query>from PSTRepresentationType p where p.realm=?</query>
        <hint name="org.hibernate.cacheable" value="true" />
    </named-query>
</entity-mappings>
```

(persistence.xml)

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
    <!-- Enables the query cache. Individual queries still have to be set cachable. -->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory" />

    <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics" value="true" />
</properties>
```

I'm using JBoss EAP 5.1 and hibernate-infinispan 3.5.6-Final.

Comment: Have you tried the programmatic way of declaring a query cacheable? i.e. query.setCacheable(true)

How do you know query cache is not working? What are you checking specificatlly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross posted http://community.jboss.org/thread/169801?tstart=0